# Python slow after mounting with sshfs

Tags: python, sshfs

I have found that my python starts up very slow after I mount an external drive using sshfs. When I unmount the drive again the the python startup is fast.

I make no mention of the mounted drive in my .bashrc or .pythonrc. Why is the python startup so slow with a mounted drive and what can I do to avoid it?

I am running Mavericks on a mac and python from Macports.

Comment: I would use a tool like [dtruss](https://opensourcehacker.com/2011/12/02/osx-strace-equivalent-dtruss-seeing-inside-applications-what-they-do-and-why-they-hang/) to check on what syscalls python stops

Comment: I'd suspect something like `stat()` or so...

Comment: I tried using dtruss but I am not sure I understand the output. It gives a long thread with output like: stat64("/AppleInternal\0", 0x7FFF5AECB768, 0x0)   = -1 Err#2
audit_session_self(0x7FFF5AECB620, 0x7FFF5AECB458, 0x4)   = 4099 0
geteuid(0x7FFF5AECB620, 0x7FFF5AECB458, 0x0)   = 0 0
getegid(0x7FFF5AECB620, 0x7FFF5AECB458, 0x0)   = 20 0
getaudit_addr(0x7FFF5AECB6F8, 0x30, 0x0)   = 0 0
csops(0xFD1A, 0x7, 0x7FFF5AECB2E0)   = -1 Err#22

Comment: Likely you should use it with time measuring options (`-d` and/or `-e`) and then check at which point of startup python freezes for a while.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your `PYTHONPATH` includes the mounted path. So every import like `import os` searches for `os` in that `PYTHONPATH`.
To speed up these imports over sshfs, you probably want to add `-o negative_timeout=1000` to `sshfs`. It tells sshfs's cache to remember for 1000 secs that it didn't find those packages there.

```
sshfs -o negative_timeout=1000  remotehost:/dir /dir
```

Caveat: you may mot see new files over sshfs for 1000 secs.